# Facebook SDK Unity Plugin - Mobile App Ads Tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK Unity Plugin in my Unity Project which I will use to create iOS and Android builds. Does anyone know how I can implement mobile app ads tracking:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#add-sdk

It mentions the code needed for iOS and Android, but how can I put these in my Unity project?

Answer (score 0):

The Unity SDK equivalent can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.PublishInstall/